# Angular 6 subject not catching subscribe event?

Tags: javascript, angular

I created a component that holds a loader:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-loader',
  templateUrl: './loader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loader.component.scss'],
  providers: [LoaderService]
})
export class LoaderComponent implements OnInit {

  showloader: boolean = false;

  constructor  (private loader_service:LoaderService) {}

  ngOnInit () {
    this.loader_service.showLoaderEventChange.subscribe(state => {
      console.log(state); // Nothing prints !!
       this.showloader = state;
    })
  }
}
```

and I have a service that I call from another component, and **the call does work**:

```
public grabJsonData (enviroment: string, language: string) {
  this.loader_service.showLoader(true);
}
```

It uses the `LoaderService`:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoaderService {

  showLoaderEventChange = new Subject<any>();

  constructor() { }

  showLoader(state){
    this.showLoaderEventChange.next(state);
  }

}
```

The loader component uses the `LoaderService`, listens for `showLoaderEventChange` to pass `next()`.

But when I do `this.showLoaderEventChange.next(state)` it does not catch anything in the `subscribe` function.

Did I miss something?

Comment: are you sure that you are using the **same** instance of service for both your components?

Comment: Well its injected, so I guess its the same static call?

Comment: Try to put the LoaderService on your app.module.ts providers to make sure the same instance is used through the all application rather than individual component injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because you are **not** using same instance of `service` for your components since you are injecting it in `root` as well as in `Loader Component`.

Try removing `Providers : [LoaderService]` from your `Loadercomponent`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Angular 6 since I haven't tested it out yet but in Angular 5 you have to create an observable to observe it from your Subject as such :

`showLoaderEventChangeEmitter = new Subject<any>();
showLoaderEventChangeEvent$ = this.showLoaderEventChangeEmitter.asObservable();`

Then use `showLoaderEventChangeEmitter.next();` to trigger events and listen to them with `showLoaderEventChangeEvent$.subscribe()`